# Help identify these Batman characters on hand-drawn trading card sketches

Tags: dc, batman, character-identification

I've recently been to DeviantArt and I found some sketches of a DC trading cards and among them a couple of characters I was unable to identify by myself. Can you help me match them with names? Many thanks in advance.

[image: Unknown 1]

My guess: Old version of the Huntress

[image: Unknown 2]
[image: Unknown 3]
[image: Unknown 4]
[image: Unknown 5]
[image: Unknown 6]

My guess: Prometheus

[image: Unknown 7]

Comment: The 4 vaguely batman looking ones could be batman in different suits/incarnations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These look to be the work of [Pablo Praino](http://optimuspraino.deviantart.com/gallery/41579282/Batman-The-Legend-Sketchcards), who is listed as one of the artists of the ["Batman: the Legend" trading cards](https://www.cryptozoic.com/trading-cards/dc-comics-batman%E2%84%A2-legend-trading-cards).

1. [Kathy Kane/Batwoman of Earth One](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Katherine_Kane_(Earth-One)) (different from the current one)
2. [Azrael-Batman](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Azrael_(Jean-Paul_Valley)) (thanks, Gallifreyan. Religious zealot who did Batman while Bruce was laid up with a broken back)
3. [Batzarro](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batzarro_(New_Earth)) (Bizarro Batman)
4. [Nightrunner](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Bilal_Asselah_(New_Earth)) (French Batman, Inc hire)
5. [Catman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catman_(comics)) (Batman mirror villain)
6. [Knight and Squire](http://comicsalliance.com/a-brief-history-of-the-knight-and-squire/) (English Batman, Inc hire)
7. [The Creeper](http://batman.wikia.com/wiki/Creeper) (aka Jack Ryder, insane vigilante)

Comment: FWIW, there's an image on that Wikia page for Azrael that appears to have inspired that sketch.

Comment: Not just Azrael! He [*was* Batman](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Batman_Vol_1_500), for a time! That was the Batsuit! (It was the 90s. Mistakes were made.)

Comment: Great answer, thanks!